Issue with Booting into Windows After Installing Additional RAM on ASUS PRIME B650M-A WIFI II
I'm experiencing an issue with my PC where it fails to boot into Windows right away after restarting. Here's the situation:
Current Setup:

Motherboard: ASUS PRIME B650M-A WIFI II
CPU: 7800x3d
RAM: 4 sticks of Corsair CMH32GX5M2B6000C38 (DDR5, 6000 MHz)

2 sticks are manufactured by Micron
2 sticks are manufactured by Samsung
that wasn't clearly advertised on the packeging I was only able to view this information through software like CPU-Z or HWiNFO
my Problem:
Upon restarting, the PC powers on with fans and LEDs active, but there's no display, and peripherals like the keyboard and mouse are unresponsive.
To boot into Windows, I have to clear the CMOS, enter the BIOS, and then exit without making any changes.
Enabling DOCP to set the RAM to its advertised 6000 MHz causes the PC to reboot into BIOS instead.
Steps Taken:
Ran Memtest86 at stock settings; all RAM sticks passed without errors.
Updated to the latest BIOS version.
Tried manually setting the frequency and timings (rather than just enabling DOCP) for RAM with no success.
Questions:
Could the difference in memory IC manufacturers (Micron vs. Samsung) be causing this issue despite having identical specifications?
Are there specific BIOS settings I should adjust to achieve stability?
Is there a more effective way to configure RAM settings for mixed-manufacturer modules?

"Could the difference in memory IC manufacturers" - No; Those manufactures followed a standard to develop the IC. Given the same module frequency and timing delay DDR is DDR.
